# svn diff not working for specific revision number

Tags: svn, meld, beyondcompare4

Below svn diff between head and working copy is fine

```
svn diff --diff-cmd=/usr/bin/meld ./path1/file1.cpp
```

But when I try to compare any remote file then it's just not showing anything

```
svn diff -r head:prev --diff-cmd=/usr/bin/meld ./path1/file1.cpp
```

Any help why this is not working?

Comment: Can you please confirm that if you leave out the `--diff-cmd... ` option, the output of both commands is exactly the same?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper It's working fine without --diff-cmd. But first running without --diff-cmd and then running with --diff-cmd it's working fine.

But I think downloading files from svn-repo-server is taking time and meanwhile the external diff utility didn't receive file for differentiating.